# No module named django.template in django 1.0.4

Tags: python, django, templates, environment-variables, virtualenv

I have old project in django 1.0.4 and viertualenv with python 2.7.
When I try one of my script i recived an error in this place:

```
from django.template import Context, loader
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "path to file.py", line 6, in from django.template import Context, loader ImportError: No module named django.template
```

Anybody had the same error like this?

**EDIT:**

Installing:

```
Collecting https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.0.4/tarball/
  Downloading https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.0.4/tarball/ (5.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.1MB 332kB/s 
  Cannot determine compression type for file /tmp/pip-KiWjIE-unpack/tarball.obj
Installing collected packages: Django
  Running setup.py install for Django ... done
Successfully installed Django-1.0.4
```

Requriments:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.0.4
MySQL-python==1.2.3
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
Pillow==4.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-memcached==1.58
six==1.10.0
```

I have also errors with: `from django.core.management import setup_environ`

Comment: why dont you upgrade it? 1.0.4 is not supported now

Comment: I know but I have only migrate issue, so upgrade issue will be in the future.

Comment: its hard, i dont know to be frank as i havent used that old version, hope someone who has worked can help you up

Comment: Django 1.0.x did have a [`django.template`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.0.x/django/template) module. I think there could be something odd with your installation that you haven't shown.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. I only have Python 3 installed at the moment, but running `from django.template import Context` with Django 1.0.4 installed resulted in an error due to incompatibility with Python 3 (I think Django started to support Python 3 only at version 1.6). The import itself works. You should try to reinstall.

Comment: @Alasdair Please check my edit.

Comment: @deepspace - I have python 2.7. I'm wondering if I need lower than 2.7.

Comment: Django 1.0 is almost ten years old. You really really really should upgrade.

Comment: The [faq from Django 1.0.x](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.0.x/docs/faq/install.txt#L21) says it supports Python 2.3 to 2.6.